# JS - How do I make this object filled dynamically by an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, material-table

I need help with the following: I am using material-table and its columns take an argument "lookup" which is an object with values. Its used for filtering and enabling multiselect inside the rows. The thing is, all examples I can find, are hardcoded, I am not able to find dynamically filled lookup objects. Now my question is; how can I fill the lookup object with values from an array:

```
 const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
 {
   title: 'Birth Place',
   field: 'birthCity',
   lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
 },
]);
```

I need an object like this:

```
{"PUE-200":"PUE-200", "PUE-201":"PUE-202" etc.}
```

The array I need to extract the data from is the following:

```
   0:{
    "ProjektNr": "PUE-200",
    "ProjektBeschreibung": "aa"
    }
   1:{
    "ProjektNr": "PUE-201",
    "ProjektBeschreibung": "aa"
    }
```

Will appriciate any help :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use ```array.reduce()``` for your case.

Comment: @Lee Everette how does this mapping work? ```ProjektNr : ProjectNr```, how do you want your items mapped?

Comment: The array I try to get into lookup is already reduced, I need the value name AND the value to be set to the project number. You can see at the lookup element of the columns array how I need the object to be. The problem is, I dont know how to get it like the second code snippet.

Comment: @Anuja Thanks for the reply. When i map the array, i get it like this back:
[
0:{ProjektNr: "PUE-200"},
1:{ProjektNr: "PUE-201"]
]

What i try to achieve is this:
{"PUE-200":"PUE-200", "PUE-201":"PUE-201"}
I need it as a single object with multiple elements

Comment: How do you want your mapping to work to get something like `"PUE-201":"PUE-202"`?

Comment: If you use ```reduce()```, you can use an initial value with an empty object ```{}```, whenever you add a new item to the object, you can check if there is an existing key in the object. If not, add the new key with values. What is your struggle?  Show us your codes.

Comment: Guys thank you all for the help, check  @DrewReese 's answer. Its exactly what I needed. Thank you nevertheless for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the array of objects to an array of key-value pairs using the `ProjektNr` property and convert back to object using [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const data = [
  {
    "ProjektNr": "PUE-200",
    "ProjektBeschreibung": "aa"
  },
  {
    "ProjektNr": "PUE-201",
    "ProjektBeschreibung": "aa"
  }
];

const newMap = Object.fromEntries(data.map(el => [el.ProjektNr, el.ProjektNr]));

console.log(newMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can see something like this is what you would need.

```
const arr = [{
    "ProjektNr": "PUE-200",
    "ProjektBeschreibung": "aa"
    },
    {
    "ProjektNr": "PUE-201",
    "ProjektBeschreibung": "aa"
    }]

    const lookup = arr.reduce((accumulator,currentValue)=>{
    return {...accumulator, [currentValue.ProjektNr]: currentValue.ProjektBeschreibung },{})
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help, Drew Reese's answer above nailed it :)